# How to loop the header in the react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

i have crated a react table , to display my product variation showing its id , variation sunch weight,width,height and so on, also its price and add to cart button in the table, I wanted to loop the header so that , the each variation name is a header in the table. i have save the data in state . below is my code of table function which I created

```js
<table {...getTableProps()} className="w-100">
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id} {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th
                  className={classnames(
                    " text-left pl-0 rt-th rt-resizable-header",
                    {
                      "-cursor-pointer": column.sortable,
                      "-sort-asc": column.isSorted && !column.isSortedDesc,
                      "-sort-desc": column.isSorted && column.isSortedDesc,
                    }
                  )}
                  key={column.id}
                  {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                >
                  <div
                    className="rt-resizable-header-content"
                    {...(column.sortable && {
                      ...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps()),
                    })}
                  >
                    {column.render("Header")}
                  </div>
                  {/* Render the columns filter UI */}
                  <div>
                    {column.canFilter ? column.render("FilterColumn") : null}
                  </div>
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody className="text-left" {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr
                key={row.id}
                {...row.getRowProps()}
                className={classnames(
                  "rt-tr text-break",
                  { " -odd": i % 2 === 0 },
                  { " -even": i % 2 === 1 }
                )}
              >
                {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                  <td key={row.id} {...cell.getCellProps()}>
                    {cell.render("Cell")}
                  </td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

below is how I save my data in the data state using useEFFECT inreact

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    setDataState(
      variation.map((variations) => ({
        sn: variations.VariationSKU,
        snId: <p className="megan-text">{variations.VariationSKU}</p>,
        attributes: variations.Attributes.map((attribute) => (
          <td key={attribute.ID} className="text-dark text-center">
            <p className="mr-5">{attribute.Value}</p>
          </td>
        )),
        price: <CurrencyFormat price={variations.Price} currency="MYR" />,
        action: (
          <Button
            id="Sproduct-btn"
            className={`btn add-to-cart w-100 ${submitResponse.class} `}
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            type="button"
            tag={!user ? Link : "a"}
            to={!user ? "/login" : ""}
            disabled={
              submitResponse.openState ||
              status === "Inactive" ||
              variationstatus === "Inactive" ||
              stock === 0 ||
              variationstock === 0
            }
            style={{ fontSize: "15px", width: "30%" }}
            {...(user && {
              onClick: () => {
                onSubmit(productid, variations.ID);
                // setResponse(addToCart(productid, variation.ID));
              },
            })}
          >
            <div className="cart">
              <div>
                <div />
                <div />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="dots" />
            {/* {variationStock === 0 || data.data.Stock === 0 ? (
    <div className="pl-2 default">SOLD OUT</div>
  ) : (
    <span className="pl-2 default">ADD TO BAG</span>
  )} */}
            <span className="pl-2 default">{result}</span>
            <div className="success">ADDED</div>
            <div className="failed">FAILED TO ADDED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN</div>
          </Button>
        ),
      }))
    );
  }, [submitResponse]);
```

```js
 const getTableHeaders = () =>
    variation.map((varian) =>
      varian.Attributes.map((attribute) => ({
        id: attribute.ID,
        Header: attribute.Name,
        accessor: String(attribute.Value),
        sortable: true,
      }))
    );
```

these are how I call the data in  where I wanted the attribute name, and value in their own column in the table. Currently, my variation are in 1 column but I wanted each attributes have its own column which I don't know how to do, can anyone pls help, thank you

```js
 {dataState !== [] && (
          <Table
            responsive
            columns={[
              {
                Header: "SN",
                accessor: "snId",
                sortable: true,
              },
              {
                ...getTableHeaders(),
              },
              {
                Header: "Price",
                accessor: "price",
                sortable: true,
              },
              {
                Header: "",
                accessor: "action",
              },
            ]}
            data={dataState}
            className="-striped -highlight primary-pagination font-weight-bold"
          />
        )}
```

this how my table looks like
[image]

these the response of variation which I used in getTableHeader

```js
"VariationList": [
        {
            "ID": "63eaf4417f339ebdb324fe33",
            "VariationSKU": "102100489N",
            "Price": 2250,
            "Attributes": [
                {
                    "ID": "63eaf3167f339ebdb324efa9",
                    "Name": "Hook",
                    "Value": "CAKUK S"
                },
                {
                    "ID": "63eaf3167f339ebdb324efa7",
                    "Name": "Weight",
                    "Value": 3.8
                },
                {
                    "ID": "63eaf3167f339ebdb324efaa",
                    "Name": "Length",
                    "Value": 28
                },
                {
                    "ID": "63eaf3167f339ebdb324efa4",
                    "Name": "Width",
                    "Value": 1.3
                }
            ],
         
        },{},{},{},{}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're only returning one column object for all three attributes. Rather than doing a map inside 1 column object, you could do a map outside. You should also have an id field in all columns with accessors - I would suggest a function like:

```
const getTableHeaders = (attributelist) =>
  attributelist.map((attribute) => ({
    id: attribute.ID,
    Header: attribute.Name,
    accessor: String(attibute.Value),
    sortable: true,
  }));
```

And then, you could use it like this:

```
columns = {[
  {
    Header: "SN",
    accessor: "snId",
    sortable: true,
  },
  ...getTableHeaders(attributelist),
  {
    Header: "Price",
    accessor: "price",
    sortable: true,
  },
  {
    Header: "",
    accessor: "action",
  },
]};
```

The key thing you're missing is that you should have 1 object per column, whereas you currently have 1 object for all 3 desired columns.

Comment: hi, update the code, i getting the error of  Uncaught Error: A column ID (or string accessor) is required!

Comment: Are you passing an argument to getTableHeaders? i.e. `...getTableHeaders(attributelist)` instead of `getTableHeaders()` in your example

Comment: ...getTableHeaders(attributelist) , I put as this, still got the same error

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like the `accessor` property should be a string. You could make sure it's a string in the getTableHeaders function - I've updated the answer to do that.

Comment: Getting this Uncaught Error: Duplicate columns were found with ids: "attr" in the columns array above